# Lossless conversion of PDF to DJVU

Tags: linux, pdf, ubuntu, djvu

I search a way for lossless, reliable and also compressed conversion of pdf files, which contain black and white text scans, to the djvu format. The tool must be a commandline program so I can atomize the conversion. I found that `djvulibre` but I was not able to make it work with the required drivers on my ubuntu linux (they seem to be separate because of license issues). `pdf2djvu` has options to adjust the loss level for image compression, but I am not sure if it will always detect the resolution of the source files correctly so that I am afraid that it may create loss due to resampling of the images. Any hints to other software, the resolution of driver issues with `djvulibre` or the proper use of `pdf2djvu` are very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can use xpdf to extract the scan images from inside your PDF files](https://superuser.com/a/289580/78499)
 
Then use imagemagick to convert each image into pbm format:

```
convert page-000.png page-000.pbm
```

Then [convert your pbm images into djvu pages with djvulibre](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Creating_a_DjVu_file#Converting_page_scans).

```
cjb2 -clean page-000.pbm page-000.djvu
```

Finally adding your new page to the final document

```
djvm -i page.djvu page-000.djvu
```

The process is partially explained here:
[Creating a DjVu file](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Creating_a_DjVu_file#Converting_page_scans)

Comment: Thanks! Will this procedure preserve the page size and the borders in the documents? I ask because in the PDF files the embedded images will not necessarily extend to the edges of the pages. The pdfimages manpage says that the `-j` option outputs PBM, so we could possibly omit the second step.

Comment: I don't think it will preserve them, but cannot think on any better way of preserving the original images and create a lossless process.

Comment: Ok, then the question arises if the borders can be copied separately from the original pdf to the final djvu. Or at least I would need a way to generate djvu which has a given fixed size, say letter or A4, and to justify the pictures on the pages.